# underscore.js _.where() equivalent in D3 or vanilla

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, microstrategy

for some reason im geting exceptiones using underscore.js in Microstrategy's Visualization Builder. So im searching for an equivalent function to _.where. How can i rewrite the function _.where() in plain javascript or D3.js. Does anyone has an idea?

Maybe its to obvious that i can't find it :)

Thanks for help!

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to StackOverflow!  You might want to take a moment to review [ask].  This question is a little sparse-- you've not provided very much detail for the community to use in attempting to assist you.  It helps to try to imagine yourself as completely new to the issue-- ask yourself: with what's provided in the question, would you have enough information/context to answer.  Welcome!

Comment: You can always access [Underscore's source code](http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js) and get the components you need.